# setting the window in javascript core ios 7

Tags: javascript, ios

I am using iOS 7's core javascript library in an attempt to get a URL for an image. I created a request to get an image from a URL, but what I get back is some javascript. From that javascript, I want to extract a string that contains the URL of the image that I want to display.  Here is the code I use to get the URL:

```
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:curURL]];
        NSString *javascriptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"data string = %@", javascriptString);
```

The javascriptString is now:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
if(window.location.search && window.location.search.length > 1){
    url += window.location.search; // #189617
}



var loc = 'https://test.myURL.com/?ec=302&startURL='+encodeURIComponent(url);
window.location = loc;
</script>
```

From this, I would like to get the loc variable

```
NSString *windowJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var window = %@", curURL];
        JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init]];
        [context evaluateScript:windowJS];
        [context evaluateScript:javascriptString];
        JSValue *locURL = context[@"loc"];
        NSLog(@"locURL: %@", locURL);
```

This variable should contain a link the jpg image that I want to display, but I am getting locURL: undefined... And then an error. Is there a way to set the window or any other solution to get the value of the loc var?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove 'var' before 'loc', turn it to a global variable.